# Adaptedness of modifications under the usual conditions

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose we have a filtration $\mathbb{F} $ which satisfies the usual conditioning so it contains all null sets and is right continuous. Now let $X_t$ with $t\in T$ be a stochastic process adapted to this filtration. I now want to prove that: if $Y_t$ is a modification of $X_t$ ($P(X_t=Y_t) =1$ for all $t$) then $Y_t$ is adapted. I don't know how to begin. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**. Let us write $\mathbb F = (\mathcal F_t)_t$. So you want to prove that $Y_t$ is $\def\F{\mathcal F}\F_t$-measurable, so let $A\subseteq \mathbb R$ a Borel set. We have $X_t^{-1}[A] \,\Delta\,Y_t^{-1}[A] \subseteq \{X_t \ne Y_t\}$. Now the latter is a null set.

Comment: Where does the $\Delta$ stand for in between the inverse images? Thanks for the hint!

Comment: For the symmetric difference of the two sets:
$$ C \,\Delta\, D = (C \cup D) \setminus (C \cap D) = (C \setminus D) \cup (D \setminus C) $$